# Oracle cursor with variables help needed

Tags: oracle, cursor, temp-tables

I am trying to do a cursor which does something like below, struggling with different approaches with no results. Seems, I won't be able to do it by myself, and decided to ask you for help.
Below code shows what I want to achieve rather than ready approach. Please help.

I dont know it it matters but note, that I need to update CUSTOMERS in loop. I also need to select some data from another table referencing customer in this loop, then insert something to third table and update customer table.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR MY_CURSOR
  IS
    SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ACTIVE = 1 ;
  MY_RECORD MY_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR MY_RECORD IN MY_CURSOR
  LOOP

 DECLARE TEMPORARY_TABLE TABLE (A DATE, B NUMBER, C VARCHAR)

 INSERT INTO @TEMPORARY_TABLE(A,B,C) (SELECT CREATEDDATE, ID, NAME FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUSTOMER = MY_RECORD.CUSTOMERID)

 INSERT INTO SOME_EVENT_TABLE(ID, NAME, DATE, ACCOUNT_ID) VALUE (some_seq.NEXTVAL, @TEMPORARY_TABLE[C], @TEMPORARY_TABLE[A], @TEMPORARY_TABLE[B])

     UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET LAST_ACCOUNT_CHECK_NAME=@TEMPORARY_TABLE(C), LAST_INSERTED_EVENT_ID = some_seq.CURRVAL  WHERE ID = MY_RECORD.CUSTOMERID


  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't declare a temporary table in Oracle like you do in SQL Server.  However, you really don't need it here anyway.

Something like this should work:

```
FOR MY_RECORD IN MY_CURSOR LOOP
  FOR  R IN (SELECT CREATEDDATE, ID, NAME 
               FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUSTOMER = MY_RECORD.CUSTOMERID) LOOP
    INSERT INTO some_event_table(ID, NAME, DATE, ACCOUNT_ID)
    VALUES (some_seq.NEXTVAL, R.NAME, R.CREATEDATE, R.ID);

    UPDATE customers 
       SET last_account_check_name = R.name
         , last_inserted_event_id = some_seq.CURRVAL
     WHERE id = MY_RECORD.CUSTOMER_ID;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: seems exactly what i need, but do I need to declare R somehow?
MY_RECORD is declared: MY_RECORD MY_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;

Comment: No, the FOR LOOP in which you use R implicitly declares it as a record of the type you're SELECTing.

Answer (score 0):

Row by row actions in SQL are terribly inefficient. You will get vastly better performance if you do this in a set-based way.

```
INSERT INTO some_event_table(ID, NAME, DATE, ACCOUNT_ID)
SELECT some_seq.NEXTVAL, a.name, a.createdate, a.id
  FROM ACCOUNT a
 INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customerid = a.customerid
 WHERE c.active = 1;

UPDATE customers 
   SET last_account_check_name = 
          ( SELECT a.name FROM account a WHERE a.customerid = c.customerid ),
       last_inserted_event_id = some_seq.CURRVAL
 WHERE c.active = 1;
```

There may be concurrency issues with that (what happens if customers is updated between the two statements?), but that might be good enough for your needs.

Comment: You're assuming there's one row inserted/updated in the SELECT/UPDATE pair, which may or may not be a valid assumption. If it's not, then your reference to the CURRVAL will not work the way you think.

Comment: Good point. I misread that as a NEXTVAL. I wonder what would be the best way to do that, then. An updatable view maybe?

Comment: That's why I did what I did in my answer :-)  I actually started down the same road you did and realized I had made a potentially inaccurate assumption.